# how to copy text from web browser textbox/input to textbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, streamwriter

I have tried:

```
TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("User1").InnerText
```

Info:
Textbox1 is where i wish for the text to be,
User1 is the input/textbox id

The code for site:

```
<input type="text" name="User"  id="Pass1" value="Uwotm8">
```

Also i've heard of methods like stream writer grabbing but i don't know anything about that yet

Comment: `TextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText();`

Comment: use innerHtml instead `TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("User1")..innerHtml`

Answer (score 1):

probably something like this

```
 TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Pass1").GetAttribute("value")
```